# Is the Chow ring of determinantal varieties known?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The 1988' book "Determinantal varieties" by Bruns and Vetter describes the Chow group of determinantal varieties in Chapter 8, but as far as I understand this book it seems to me that relations between intersections of these classes are not treated there.

Is there a reference describing the whole structure of the Chow ring of determinantal varieties (i.e. varieties defined by the vanishing of all $(r+1)$-minors of a generic $n\times m$ matrix)?
Or perhaps this question does not make sense since determinantal varieties are singular (but they are normal), so perhaps it is not even possible to define properly an intersection ring for the classes of divisors?

If this Chow ring is known, then is there also a similar description for the Chow ring of symmetric determinantal varieties (i.e. varieties defined by the vanishing of all $(r+1)$-minors of a generic symmetric $n\times n$ matrix)?

Comment: Normality doesn't help much for defining intersection products in general, but you could of course intersect any cycle with a Cartier divisor.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  The space of complete collineations is a minimal wonderful resolution of singularities that is "Chow trivial", i.e., the pushforward map on Chow groups is surjective.  Thus, you can compute the ring of bivariant Chow classes as the subring of the Chow ring of the space of complete collineations of all classes that preserve the kernel of the pushforward map.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments, I will look at this space of complete collineations.